# Did Lucius and Bellatrix have an affair?

Tags: harry-potter

In the books he called her Bella and he actually grabbed her hand in Malfoy Manor to which she aggressively responded by telling him to take his hands off her. There's sexual tension here.

> “I was about to call him!” said Lucius, and his hand actually closed upon Bellatrix’s wrist, preventing her from touching the Mark.
>
> “I shall summon him, Bella, Potter has been brought to my house, and it is therefore upon my authority –”
>
> “Your authority!” she sneered, attempting to wrench her hand from his grasp. “You lost your authority when you lost your wand, Lucius! How dare you! Take your hands off me!”

Comment: I don’t see sexual tension in that passage. Regular old disagreement and danger, yes.

Comment: Don't forget that Lucius was married to Bella's sister. What we've got here is a good old family quarrel.

Answer (score 4):

The only reason for Lucius grabbing Bellatrix's hand here is to stop her from pressing her Dark Mark. The only reason for Bellatrix telling him to take his hands off her is that she considers herself to be Voldemort's most faithful supporter and she wants to be the one to summon him. She doesn't want him to take the glory, she considered him inferior, she thinks he's a failure as a Death Eater, etc etc.